# smashoperator overlaps big parentheses with limits

Tags: math-mode

`\smashoperator` pulls big parentheses too close causing them to overlap with the limits. Is there any workaround?

Edit: An ad-hoc solution is to force an appropriate amount of empty space to the right/left of the left/right parentheses using `\,` `\quad` etc. But these "tricks" obviously defeat the whole point of using LaTeX.

Example:

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

$\lambda\left(\smashoperator{\bigcup_{x=lowerlimit}^{upperlimit}} f(x) \right)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\smashoperator` does precisely what it should do here. What result did you expect? (_Maybe try `\smashoperator[r]`?_)

Comment: I expected that only f(x) would get pulled close and that the parentheses would stay outside the limits. I believe that is a reasonable expectation. And although with the current example, \smashoperator[r] luckily seems to avoid overlap, if you change the limits to "x=longlowerlimit" and "longupperlimit" then the overlap again occurs.

Comment: It does what it does, how should `\smashoperator` know there is a fence behind it?

Comment: I'm no (La)TeX expert, but I think it should be possible to modify \smashoperator to consider this case. I think the creators never considered this possibility.

Comment: Not unless someone provide it. There will be a lot of special cases to consider, so it would be a lot easier to use a different solution in the cases where `\smashoperator` does not fit.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, it's very difficult to define a `\smashoperator` command that deals with all possible cases involving long limits. To understand why it is difficult, you need to know a little about boxes in `TeX`. Roughly speaking, horizontally smashed boxes (the limits in this case) are considered to have zero width, and there is no easy way to say

> Small objects should consider the
>   limits to be smashed, but large
>   objects should
>   not.

which is what you need.

The following code seems to work in your case, but will probably fail in others that I have not considered. In my opinion it would be better to avoid long limits, because they are grotesque (perhaps this is why the author(s) of `mathtools` did not provide an easy way to construct them).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\test}[4]{ %
  %
  \newbox\bigbox
  \newbox\smallbox
  \newbox\argbox
  \newdimen\smallwidth
  \newdimen\offsetwidth
  \newdimen\argwidth
  %
  %Store the unsmashed operator in \bigbox. 
  \sbox\bigbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #1_{#2}^{#3}}}
  %Now store the smashed operator in \smallbox. 
  \sbox\smallbox{\ensuremath{\smashoperator{#1_{#2}^{#3}}}}
  %Finally, store the argument in \argbox
  \sbox\argbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle \,#4}}
  %Calculate the width of the argument
  \argwidth=\wd\argbox
  %
  %Calculate the width by which the limits protrude. Note:
  %this will evaluate to zero if the limits do not protrude.
  \offsetwidth=\wd\bigbox
  \smallwidth=\wd\smallbox
  \multiply\smallwidth by -1
  \advance\offsetwidth by \smallwidth
  \divide\offsetwidth by 2
  %
  %Place the unsmashed operator and the argument on the page, 
  %pulling back the argument by the appropriate distance.
  \usebox\bigbox\hspace{-\offsetwidth}\usebox\argbox
  %
  %If the width of the argument is less than the width of
  %the protrusion, we now need to add some more space.
  \ifnum\offsetwidth>\argwidth \hspace{\offsetwidth}\hspace{-\argwidth} \fi
  %
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left[\test{\bigcup}{longlimit}{longlimit}{f(x)} \right]
\quad
\left[\test{\bigcup}{veryverylonglimit}{veryverylonglimit}{f(x)} \right]
\quad
\left[\test{\bigcup}{x}{y}{f(x)} \right]
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```